# How do industrial PSUs switch to 4-wire measurement?

Tags: differential, voltage-measurement

Almost all high end PSUs provide a 4-wire voltage measurement at the load, How do they switch to 4-wire measurement?

Is it in software, reading another ADC channel or they use a relay? Can it be done without user choosing 4-wire measurement in the menu, just by connecting the wires it switch to 4-wire measurement automatically?

Comment: why would they need to switch? It's not clear why they would be switching.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's automatic. On the PSU PCB, the sense terminals are connected to the main terminals through resistors, typically about 100Ω. This provides the feedback in the absence of any external sense connection. If you do make external sense connections, these resistors are effectively shorted out. Since the sense inputs are high impedance, the resistors do not introduce any significant error.

Comment: Just wondering: Is it as low as 100 Ω? I've never measured them but if there was, say, a 1 V drop along the main feed wire that would be 10 mA flowing through the sense resistor and out to the load too.

Comment: @Transistor: Yes, but that does not cause any trouble. It just (very slightly) reduces the wiring voltage drop. It has no effect on the accuracy of the feedback, assuming that the sense wires themselves have no appreciable drop @ 10 mA.